# jqgrid remove empty header cell after the last column

Tags: jqgrid, header

There is a weird behavior in my jqgrid. I suddenly noticed that there is a blank header cell after my last column and I want to get rid of it. Any idea how?

[image]

Here is the definition of my jqgrid:

```
myGrid.jqGrid({
    colNames: ['Order Id', 'a', b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
      j', 'k', 'l', 'm'],
    colModel: [
      { name: 'OrderId', index: 'OrderId', width: 58, editable: false, align: 'center' },
      { name: 'a', index: 'a', width: 68, editable: false, align: 'center', sortable: false },
      { name: 'b', index: 'b', width: 43, editable: false, align: 'center', sortable: false },
      { name: 'c', index: 'c', width: 48, editable: false, align: 'center', sortable: false },
      { name: 'd', index: 'd', width: 63, editable: false, align: 'center', sortable: false },
      { name: 'e', index: 'e', width: 123, editable: false, align: 'center', sortable: false },
      { name: 'f', index: 'f', width: 73, editable: false, align: 'center', sortable: false },
      { name: 'g', index: 'g', width: 123, editable: false, align: 'center', sortable: false },
      { name: 'h', index: 'h', width: 73, editable: false, align: 'center', sortable: false },
      { name: 'i', index: 'i', width: 78, editable: false, align: 'center', sortable: false },
      { name: 'j', index: 'j', width: 117, editable: false, align: 'center', sortable: false },
      { name: 'k', index: 'k', width: 53, editable: false, align: 'center', sortable: false },
      { name: 'l', index: 'l', width: 73, editable: false, align: 'center', sortable: false},
      { name: 'm', index: 'm', width: 43, editable: false, align: 'center', sortable: false}        ],
    pginput: false,
    pgbuttons: false,
    hidegrid: false,
    pager: '#divPager',
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 20,
    caption: 'Trading Positions',
    loadonce: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    recordtext: "",
    emptyrecords: "No trading positions to display",
    shrinkToFit: false
  });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The empty space is reserved for the possible vertical scrollbar. If you place `height: "auto"` or `height: "100%"` or if you would use `scrollOffset: 0` it will be no additional empty space displayed in the grid.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! indeed the height was the cause :)

Comment: @Oleg i did scrollOffSet:0 , but as soon as the vertical scroll comes in the table , that blank header comes , any way to hide/remove it permanently.

Comment: @Vikas: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Why vertical scroll comes in the grid in your scenario?

Comment: I have given height to the grid of  100px and the td(s) height are set by .setRowData with each cell size is around 50px , so in this case vertical scroll is coming with that blank header on the right most
using (free jqGrid)

Comment: @Vikas: I still don't understand what you do. Do you use now `scrollOffset: 0` or not? **Which version of jqGrid you use (can use)?** The behavior of jqGrid is very different in different versions of jqGrid. You wrote that you use `setRowData`. Do you set large data, which increase the height of some cells or you use 3-d parameter of `setRowData` to set `height` property on the row? If you use

Comment: @Vikas: If you use free jqGrid fork, which I develop, than the problem with that blank space on the right size don't exist in the most cases (independent on the usage of `scrollOffset`). Moreover you can explicitly call `fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding` method by  `myGrid[0]fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding()` to recalculate the place for the vertical scrollbar. You can make the call after `setRowData`, for example.

Comment: @Oleg I was using the older version of the jqGrid which had the issue, in new version its fixed , thanks for the help

Comment: @Vikas: You are welcome! It's good, that the current version hasn't the problem.