# One column with autfit to jqgrid size

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have jqGrid with 2 columns, 1 is hidden and I want to make the width of 2nd column to autofit to grid size.

can anybody help me?

I have highlighted the empty area.

```
  SelectedContactPerson = xmlString;
$("#ContactPersons").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'xmlstring',
    datastr: xmlString.XmlToString(),
    mtype: 'POST',
    beforeRequest: function () {
        //alert('beforeRequest');
    },
    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
        $(this).HideBusy();
        //   alert(status);
        //     alert(error);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    },
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        var CntctCode = $("#ContactPersons").jqGrid('getCell', id, 'CntctCode');
        SelectedContactPerson.find("OCPR>row").each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).find('CntctCode').text() == CntctCode) {
                var v1 = $(this).XmlToString();
                var v2 = '<OCPR>' + v1 + '</OCPR>';
                $(this).SetValuesToControl("BusinessPartner #CP", $($.parseXML(v2)));
            }
        });
    },
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        var top_rowid = $('#ContactPersons tr:nth-child(2)').attr('id');
        $("#ContactPersons").setSelection(top_rowid, true);
        $(this).HideBusy();
    },
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    xmlReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "OCPR", row: 'row' },
    colNames: ['CntctCode', 'Name'],
    colModel: [
                        { name: 'CntctCode', key: true, index: 'CntctCode asc', hidden: true },
                        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', sortable: false, align: "left"  }
           ],
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    autowidth:true,
     shrinkToFit:false,
    height: 150,
    width: 100
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchOnEnter: false, search: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: false });
```

[image]

I am expecting the highlighted column must be hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your code I can say that your first column is hidden.. The space which you have highlighted is not because of that hidden column.. its the space allocated for scrollbar. When you will have more records the scrollbar will be visible.

have a look at [jqgrid remove empty header cell after the last column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800223/jqgrid-remove-empty-header-cell-after-the-last-column)

Hope this will help you.