# How to set overflow auto on grid headers in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid, tags

If jqgrid is empty `overflow:auto` is not applying on headers but if records are in jqgrid `overflow:auto` is working on both records and headers.

How to set horizontal scrollable in jqgrid as common on both headers and on row data, with records without records.

**Header Columns are cut off** when columns are more than 6, here overflow is not working.

Below is the image for jqgrid without records.

[image: jqgrid overflow not working on records]

Below is the image for Jqgrid with records. here overflow (horizontal scrolling) is working as common on both headers and row data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some ways to solve your problems, change **css**:

```
table.ui-jqgrid-btable { height: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px;}
```

And if you don't want scrollbar you can do this:

In `jqGrid` definition set `autowidth: true, scrollOffset:0,`.

Comment: I added `autowidth: true` In jqgrid definition, now one empty extra column is displayed at the end of `header field`.

Comment: empty little column, yes?

Comment: maby it's different problem. can you post screenshot?

Comment: After adding `autowidth:true` in jqgrid definition the jqgrid looks like [jqgrid headers autowidth set as true](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1141949159514)

Comment: I beleave this the complete answer why this column is showing and how to hide it http://stackoverflow.com/a/14802085/1849444

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67660/discussion-between-pudaykiran-and-teo-van-kot).

Comment: @pudaykiran: I would recommend you to use better `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-btable { min-height: 1px; }`

Comment: @Oleg horizontal scrolling is not shown if I use above css classes.

Comment: @pudaykiran: Which web browser you used in your tests?

Comment: @Oleg in both IE and Firefox browsers.